# Apply custom attributes to properties programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am consuming an API of business objects where I don't have access to the code. I use these objects directly on my razor views and want to be able to be able to apply my custom displayName attributes after the object(s) have been instantiated.

So, instead of this:

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string GivenName;
```

I would like to do:

```
Profile.GivenName.DisplayName("FirstName");
```

I understand how create the custom attribute, but am having troubles with making them programmatic.

Once I can do this, I can apply more of my DataAnnotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not instead derive a class from the business object and use the [MetaDataType Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx)?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IMyAttributes))
public DerivedClass : BusinessClass
{
}

public interface IMyAttributes
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I was trying to avoid creating an extra layer, but the interface idea is good. I could then apply custom attributes to the interface?

Comment: yes you can apply attributes on an interface and on properties of an interface.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if the types are not sealed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own ModelMetadataProvider and have it look up the metadata from some other source.

See the abstract class here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataprovider.aspx

The default provider uses DataAnnotations, but you could just as easily write one that looks at a SQL database or XML file or something similar.